# Gurobi - Python Portfolio Optimization: Add stock concentration limit

Tags: gurobi

I'm trying to add a stock concentration limit to the Ipython Gurobi notebook below.  I thought it would be  [m.addConstr(portvars) <= 0.15, "limit")]; but I get an error message (see message below).  Anyone have any idea how I could add a concentration limit?

https://anaconda.org/mcg/markowitz/notebook

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bool' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I think you are attempting to put a bound on variables. You can add upper bound values to your calls to `model.addVar()` (or `addVars()`).

Answer (score 0):

[`Model.addConstr()`](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addconstr.html) takes a `TempConstr` object, so you probably want to write something like `m.addConstr(sum(portvars) <= 0.15, "limit")`.